# React hooks accordion toggles all blocks instead of one

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

With a React Accordion I wanted to create a function that will only show the information of the belonging episode. But now it seems that all blocks are doing the same thing. How can I build that function so one block will be toggling instead of all?

[Link to CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/chiholiu10/react-graphql?file=/src/components/HomePage/HomePage.tsx)

```js
export const HomePage: React.FC<IProps> = () => {
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <div>{data.characters.results.map((character: { id: number, name: string, image: string; episode: any; }, index: number) => (
      <div key={character.id}>
        <CharacterHeading>{character.name}</CharacterHeading>
        <CharacterImage src={character.image} alt={character.name} />
        {character.episode.map((char: { name: string; air_date: string; episode: string; characters: any, id: number; }) => (
          <div key={char.id}>

            {char.name}
            {char.air_date}
            {char.episode}
            <AccordionButton open={open}
              onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
              Check all characters
            </AccordionButton>
            <EpisodeListSection open={open}>
              {char.characters.map((ep: { id: number, name: string; image: string; }, index: number) => (
                <EpisodeInfo key={ep.id}>
                  <EpisodeInfoBlock>
                    <EpisodeName>{ep.name}</EpisodeName>
                    <EpisodeImage src={ep.image} alt={ep.name} />
                  </EpisodeInfoBlock>
                </EpisodeInfo>
              ))}
            </EpisodeListSection>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    ))
    }</div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Well create another component which will contain Accordian manage state in that.

Comment: Would be great if you share a snippet

Comment: send me your whole code

Comment: Check updated post--> https://codesandbox.io/s/github/chiholiu10/react-graphql?file=/src/components/HomePage/HomePage.tsx

Comment: Added code in Answer please check and let me know if it works for you, I did check in the sandbox

Answer (score 1):

You only have one `open` variable that you are passing to every accordion. Thus, when one accordion changes that value with `setOpen`, it changes for all of them.

If AccordionButton is a component you built, I would suggest letting that component handle its own open/closed state. Your parent doesn't seem like it needs to control that. Otherwise, you will need `open` to be an array of values, you will need to only pass the correct `open` value to each accordion, and you will need to have your `onClick` function tell the parent which `open` value it needs to change.

Again, that seems like a lot of work for not a lot of utility. Better to just let the accordions keep track of whether they're open.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code that you can use:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import {
  AccordionButton,
  CharacterImage,
  CharacterHeading,
  EpisodeInfo,
  EpisodeImage,
  EpisodeInfoBlock,
  EpisodeListSection,
  EpisodeName
} from "./HomePage.styles";

export const GET_CHARACTER = gql`
  query {
    characters(page: 2, filter: { name: "rick" }) {
      results {
        name
        image
        gender
        episode {
          id
          name
          air_date
          episode
          characters {
            id
            name
            image
          }
        }
      }
    }
    location(id: 1) {
      id
    }
    episodesByIds(ids: [1, 2]) {
      id
    }
  }
`;

export interface Episodes {
  name: string;
  air_data: string;
  episode: string;
  characters: Array<any>;
}

export interface IProps {
  episodeList?: Episodes[];
}

export const HomePage: React.FC<IProps> = () => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_CHARACTER);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(0);

  const onChangeHandler = (text: string) => {
    setInputValue(text);
  };

  const onSelectItem = (selectedItemId: number) => {
    if (selectedId !== selectedItemId) {
      setSelectedId(selectedItemId);
    } else {
      setSelectedId(-1);
    }
  };

  if (loading) return <p>loading</p>;
  if (error) return <p>ERROR: {error.message}</p>;
  if (!data) return <p>Not found</p>;

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        onChange={(event) => onChangeHandler(event.target.value)}
        value={inputValue}
      />
      <div>
        {data.characters.results.map(
          (
            character: {
              id: number;
              name: string;
              image: string;
              episode: any;
            },
            index: number
          ) => (
            <div key={character.id}>
              <CharacterHeading>{character.name}</CharacterHeading>
              <CharacterImage src={character.image} alt={character.name} />
              {character.episode.map(
                (char: {
                  name: string;
                  air_date: string;
                  episode: string;
                  characters: any;
                  id: number;
                }) => (
                  <div key={char.id}>
                    {char.name}
                    {char.air_date}
                    {char.episode}
                    <AccordionButton
                      onClick={() => onSelectItem(char.id)}
                      open={char.id === selectedId ? true : false}
                    >
                      Check all characters
                    </AccordionButton>
                    <EpisodeListSection
                      open={char.id === selectedId ? false : true}
                    >
                      {char.characters.map(
                        (
                          ep: { id: number; name: string; image: string },
                          index: number
                        ) => (
                          <EpisodeInfo key={ep.id}>
                            <EpisodeInfoBlock>
                              <EpisodeName>{ep.name}</EpisodeName>
                              <EpisodeImage src={ep.image} alt={ep.name} />
                            </EpisodeInfoBlock>
                          </EpisodeInfo>
                        )
                      )}
                    </EpisodeListSection>
                  </div>
                )
              )}
            </div>
          )
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This will only allow one accordion to be open at a time, right?

Comment: There are also episodes with 2 arrays instead of one...those are not working with this function...

Comment: i have given the logic you can achieve with same kind of logic'